# Java: Read InputStreamReader to String - Adding extra characters

Tags: java, zip

I am using zip4j to extract zip files in Android. I want to read a file from the zip file without saving it somewhere. I have got it working but it adds extra characters towards the end of the file. The extra characters are part of the file earlier.

```
is = zipFile.getInputStream(fileHeader);

            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");

            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            char[] buffer = new char[BUFF_SIZE];
            while (isr.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length) != -1) {
                String ans = new String(buffer);
                //strUnzipped += new String(buffer);
                strUnzipped += ans;
                list.add(ans);

            }
```

I have used the list to see where the extra characters are inserted. It's inserted at the last line. and the extra text if from the previous line. In a way, it's more like the buffer did not get cleared and it replaced only part of the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

The `buffer` variable has no notion of how many characters that the prior `read` placed in it. You need to record the result of the read operation and use it in your string construction:

```
    int charsRead;
    while ((charsRead = isr.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
        String ans = new String(buffer, 0, charsRead);
        ...
    }
```

That, however, is a poor way to read what is presumably text content. If you're trying to build a giant string containing the file content, you could:

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while ((charsRead = isr.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
        sb.append(buffer, 0, charsRead);
    }
    strUnzipped = sb.toString();
```

or, if you wanted a `List<String>` with each entry being a single line from the file then:

```
    LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(isr);
    String inputLine;
    while((inputLine = lnr.readLine()) != null) {
        list.add(inputLine);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Usual problem. You're not using the value returned by `read()` correctly.

```
while (isr.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length) != -1) {
    String ans = new String(buffer);
```

should be

```
int count;
while ((count = isr.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    String ans = new String(buffer, 0, count);
```

> it's more like the buffer did not get cleared and it replaced only part of the buffer.

It's more like the buffer stayed how it was beyond the read count that was advised. Buffers don't get 'cleared'.